# Error with React Native and React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to learn React Native and got stuck with React Navigation. I have installed NPM and expo CLI. Also followed the react documentation to create the React Project. But when I tried to create navigation between screens got this error  on expo mobile client -

[image]
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I searched for hours on StackOverflow but none of the solutions worked. I am seeking a bit guidance from experts. Below I am pasting the source -

```
======    
App.js
======
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './screen/HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './screen/DetailsScreen';

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen
  },
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<AppStackNavigator />);
  }
}


=============
HomeScreen.js
=============
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

/* StyleSheet */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#efefef', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'},
});

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;


================
DelaitsScreen.js
================
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

/* StyleSheet */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#efefef', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'},
});

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailsScreen;
```

To The Experts, I will be forever grateful if anyone can nudge me to the right direction. :)

Thank You.

Comment: Your code seems fine.Which version of react-native is it??

Comment: It should be some version issue.Try upgrading/downgrading react-naviagtion

Comment: Here's what I'm using as versions :
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-navigation": "2.11.2",

Comment: Hello Guys, Thanks for the suggestion. React Version - 16.3.1, React Native Version - 0.55.4 and React Navigation Version - 3.0.0-alpha.6. It is installed with expo so i think it is default loaded.Let me try out the downgraded version.

Comment: @WiFi - Thank you for your suggestions. I deleted my node_module folder and edited the package.json file to use "react-navigation": "2.11.2" and VOILA!!!! it is working. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @pritesh - Thank you for your suggestions. I deleted my node_module folder and edited the package.json file to use "react-navigation": "2.11.2" and VOILA!!!! it is working. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Cool...........

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because it seems like you are using React Navigation V3 with code that is for V2. V3 requires [a container](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#breaking-changes).

Either downgrade to V2 or add the container.

Comment: Hester, thank you for your answer. I will try it using the updated method.